# SQL Procedure: Removing duplicates, reassigning foreign key references

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working for a company that handles ranked competitions.

Unfortunately, their member table has no unique constraint on emails, and some users have been creating a new account with the same email for each race or team they're in.

I want to place a unique constraint on the column to prevent any duplicates in the future, but...

**The problem:** How can I remove the duplicates **with a single query** without losing the data connected to them?

I figure it has something to do with updating all the foreign keys to match one instance of a user and then deleting the duplicates.

Clarification:
In the example below, the marked rows refer to the duplicate members with ID's: 03, 04, 05 and 06.
In this case, the solution would be:

1. Foreign key references with ID's 03 and 05 changed to 01.
2. Foreign key references with ID's 04 and 06 changed to 02.
3. Duplicate members with ID's 03, 04, 05 and 06 deleted.

But how can this be done in MSSQL?

```
Member table
ID | Username | Gender | Email
01 | User1    | Male   | fake@fu.bar
02 | User2    | Female | alsofake@fu.bar
*03 | User3    | Male   | fake@fu.bar
*04 | User4    | Female | alsofake@fu.bar
*05 | User5    | Male   | fake@fu.bar
*06 | User6    | Female | alsofake@fu.bar


MemberToTeam table
MemberID_fk | TeamID_fk
01          | 01
02          | 01
*03          | 02
*04          | 02
*05          | 03
*06          | 03

RaceRank table
RaceID_fk | MemberID_fk | Ranking
01        | 01          | 12
01        | 02          | 1
*02        | 03          | 5
*02        | 04          | 7
*03        | 05          | 4
*03        | 06          | 9
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please show some sample data to go with your explanation.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. Thanks for the comment. :)

Comment: Your steps in your scenario are exactly what you need to do. Update the foreign key references and then delete the duplicates. Not sure what you are asking. This is an UPDATE statement followed by a DELETE statement.

Comment: @SeanLange It's beyond me how I can write a procedure that does this without doing it member by member. Does that clarify the question to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does it in one query. Repeat for the other table.

```
with FAKES as
(
select Email
from Member
group by Email
having count(id) >1
),
FAKE_ID as
(
select id, email, row_number() over(partition by email order by id) as c_id
from Member
where email in (select Email from FAKES)
)
,
DEDUP as
(
select fi.id, f2.id as val_id
from FAKE_ID fi
inner join FAKE_ID f2
  on fi.email = f2.email
where fi.c_id > 1
and f2.c_id = 1
)
update mt
set mt.MemberID_fk = dd.val_id
from MemberToTeam mt
inner join DEDUP dd
on dd.id = mt.MemberID_fk;
```

Tested [here](http://rextester.com/TVJXG84775)

Answer (score 3):

This code will solve the problem

```
--MemberToTeam
;with cte_dupes as
(
select ID,Email,
    row_number() over (partition by Email order by Email) rn
from Member 
)
update mt
    set MemberID_fk = (select cte.ID from cte_dupes cte where rn=1 and cte.Email = m.Email)
from MemberToTeam mt
inner join Member m on m.ID = mt.MemberID_fk
inner join cte_dupes cte on cte.ID = mt.MemberID_fk and cte.rn > 1;


--RaceRank
;with cte_dupes as
(
select ID,Email,
    row_number() over (partition by Email order by Email) rn
from Member 
)
update r
    set MemberID_fk = (select cte.ID from cte_dupes cte where rn=1 and cte.Email = m.Email)
from RaceRank r
inner join Member m on m.ID = r.MemberID_fk
inner join cte_dupes cte on cte.ID = r.MemberID_fk and cte.rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to update every other table that links, via foreign key, to the member table.

You could choose a single record to rely on in the members table, out of all the records that share the same email address, and then update the linked tables with a query like this:

```
update myreferencetable set memberid = [the single instance of the member] 
where memberid in (select memberid from member where email = [email address with duplicates]
```

Comment: Hey Lorin! If you can write that query so I don't have to update the member table member by member, I'll accept it. Working with thousands of records, it would take longer than I'll be employed by this company. ;)